# How to extract foldername and filename together from the file path in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, function, t-sql, stored-procedures

I am trying to extract

```
category1/filename.txt
```

from the path

```
/path/to/foldername/category1/filename.txt
```

I have created a function in SQL and was able to get just `/filename.txt`, but need the foldername as well.

P.S. the path can be dynamic, only want the last two entities from the complete folder path.
Code:

```
(
    @Path NVARCHAR(MAX)
)
RETURNS NVARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @FileName NVARCHAR(MAX)
    
    DECLARE @ReversedPath NVARCHAR(MAX)

    SET @ReversedPath = REVERSE(@Path)
    SELECT @FileName = RIGHT(@Path, CHARINDEX('\', @ReversedPath))

    RETURN @FileName
END
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is with a couple of nested `CHARINDEX` functions and `REVERSE`:

```
DECLARE @YourString nvarchar(256) = '/path/to/foldername/category1/filename.txt';

SELECT @YourString,
       RIGHT(@YourString, CI2.I-1)
FROM (VALUES(CHARINDEX('/',REVERSE(@YourString))))CI1(I)
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(CHARINDEX('/',REVERSE(@YourString),CI1.I+1)))CI2(I);
```